# What should I do with garlic I planted as whole cloves instead of breaking them up?

Tags: garlic

I planted whole cloves of garlic without breaking them up a few weeks ago. Now I see I should have broken them... they have formed lots of roots and small shoots. Should I break them up now? or just cut my losses and let it grow from here?

Comment: Mostly anecdotal but if you have good spouts, you can most likely separate and replant. Oh and plant in fall so the resulting bulbs are bigger in the summer harvest

Comment: Do you mean you planted whole 'heads' of garlic, or whole 'cloves' of garlic? If whole heads, I would agree - did them up, separate the cloves, and replant. You have nothing to lose even if some of the plants die. If you meant whole cloves, that is exactly what you are supposed to do, so you are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the bulb out of the ground, separate them into cloves and plant them again.  If you don't you'll end up with tightly crowded garlic bulbs each competing with each other for space and nutrients. ( bulb formation needs some cold weather )

If you've got a root system, and some leaves, you'll be fine.